# I cant able to understand this code i am getting 6 as output?

Tags: java, shadow

please explain this code i am getting the output as 6,anyone please help me.

```
class A {
    static int i=1111;
    static {
        i=i-- - --i;
    }
    {
        i=i++ + ++i;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static {
        i=--i - i--;
    }
    {
        i=++i + i++; 
    }
}
public class Shadow2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println("Find->" + b.i);
    }
}
```

output

```
Find->6
```

Anyone help me to go through the code

Comment: Use a debugger and you can examine every expression during runtime.

Comment: @paxdiablo There is no undefined behaviour in Java. Evaluation order is strictly defined (mostly left-to-right), and the effect of multiple modifications in a single statement is strictly defined (although I don't remember what it's defined as).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first in static A->  
 i=i-- - --i;   will be 2 becoz, i-- means first assign value and then decrement the value so,i--=1111 then in satic memory i will be 1110 then --i means first decrement and then assign so, in this 1110 will become 1109 and then value of i wiil be 2.
secondly in static B->
currently i is 2.   i=--i - i--;   will be i=1-1  i will be zero
third instance block of A will be executed->
i=i++ + ++i  will be i=0+2=2
finaly instance block of B will be executed->
i=++i + i++   will be i=3+3=6
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be 6.

first static

`i=i-- - --i; // (1111) - (1110-1) // result 2`
second static
`i=--i - i--;  // (1 - 1) // result 0`
first block 
`i=i++ + ++i;  // (0 + [1+1]) // result 2`
second block
`i=++i + i++  // ( [2+1] + [3]) //6 // final output 6`